Horizontal listview.builder doesnt scroll in a container inside a stack widget in flutter
I cant get my listview.builder to scroll inside a column which is inside a container which is inside a stack
Listview.builder code

  SizedBox(
                    height: 150.h,
                    width: width,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0.w, right: 16.w),
                            child: Container(
                                width: 319.w,
                                height: 150.h,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.r),
                                    color: secondaryColor),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 16.r,
                                            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                              Assets.reviewsImagesRione,
                                              width: 32.w,
                                              height: 32.h,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          addHorizontalSpacing(8.w),
                                          Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                'Sharon gem',
                                                style:
                                                    kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(
                                                        fontSize: 16.sp,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.w600),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                '2 days ago',
                                                style:
                                                    kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(
                                                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      addVerticalSpacing(8.h),
                                      Text(
                                        'Had such an amazing session with Maria. She instantly picked up on the level of my fitness and adjusted the workout to suit me whilst also pushing me to my limits.',
                                        style: kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(
                                          fontSize: 13.sp,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),

Full screen code
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:dev_muscles/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:dev_muscles/constants/styles.dart';
import 'package:dev_muscles/custom_paints/achievements.dart';
import 'package:dev_muscles/generated/assets.dart';
import 'package:dev_muscles/ui/widgets/reused_heading.dart';
import 'package:dev_muscles/ui/widgets/reviews_avatar%20widget.dart';
import 'package:dev_muscles/ui/widgets/spacings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class TrainerDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrainerDetails({super.key});

  @override
  State<TrainerDetails> createState() => _TrainerDetailsState();
}

class _TrainerDetailsState extends State<TrainerDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Image.asset(Assets.imagesTrainerDetailImage),
          Positioned(
            top: 45.h,
            left: 20.w,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 16.r,
              backgroundColor: textColorWhite.withOpacity(0.2),
              child: Center(
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  color: textColorWhite,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 250,
            child: Container(
              height: 611.h,
              width: width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: backgroundColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30.r),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30.r),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 8.w, right: 8.w, top: 16.h, bottom: 16.h),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Jennifer James',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: textColorWhite,
                                fontSize: 24.sp,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                            addVerticalSpacing(8.h),
                            Text(
                              'Functional Strength',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: textColorWhite.withOpacity(0.5),
                                fontSize: 14.sp,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        // call phone button
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 27.r,
                          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            Assets.iconsCallIcon,
                            width: 19.w,
                            height: 19.h,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      size: Size(
                          327.w,
                          (327.w * 0.3333333333333333)
                              .toDouble()), //You can Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
                      painter: AchievementCustomPainter(),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 32, top: 19, right: 32, bottom: 19),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '6',
                                  style:
                                      kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(fontSize: 22),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Experience',
                                  style:
                                      kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(fontSize: 11),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '46',
                                  style:
                                      kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(fontSize: 22),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Completed',
                                  style:
                                      kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(fontSize: 11),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '65',
                                  style:
                                      kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(fontSize: 22),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Active clients',
                                  style:
                                      kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(fontSize: 11),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const ReusedHeader(
                    heading: 'Reviews',
                    subHeading: '',
                  ),
                  addVerticalSpacing(14.h),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0.w, right: 8.0.w),
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          ProgressiveAvatars(
                            numberOfAvatars: 4,
                            avatarRadius: 16.r,
                            height: 32.h,
                            extraAvatarText: '174',
                            imageUrls: [
                              Assets.reviewsImagesRione,
                              Assets.reviewsImagesRitwo,
                              Assets.reviewsImagesRithree,
                              Assets.reviewsImagesRifour,
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text('Read all reviews',
                              style: kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 14.sp, color: primaryColor)),
                        ]),
                  ),
                  addVerticalSpacing(32.h),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 150.h,
                    width: width,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0.w, right: 16.w),
                            child: Container(
                                width: 319.w,
                                height: 150.h,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.r),
                                    color: secondaryColor),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 16.r,
                                            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                              Assets.reviewsImagesRione,
                                              width: 32.w,
                                              height: 32.h,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          addHorizontalSpacing(8.w),
                                          Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                'Sharon gem',
                                                style:
                                                    kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(
                                                        fontSize: 16.sp,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.w600),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                '2 days ago',
                                                style:
                                                    kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(
                                                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      addVerticalSpacing(8.h),
                                      Text(
                                        'Had such an amazing session with Maria. She instantly picked up on the level of my fitness and adjusted the workout to suit me whilst also pushing me to my limits.',
                                        style: kNormalStyleWhite.copyWith(
                                          fontSize: 13.sp,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

What modifications do i need to do? The first generated widget is showing but it isnt scrolling, and if i reduce the width of the generated widget, i can see that it shows a couple of them but still doesnt scroll to reveal the rest.
Any help would be greatly appreciated


Can you provide minimal snippet that will reproduce the same error?

The code for the listview.builder is provided, it works if i use it as a standalone app, but not in the full code i provided.

Also its important to note that surprisingly i dont get an error in terminal even when the scrolling doesnt work. I found this quite confusing

You may run the full code i provided with dummy values and see the error in action
